# Why is using three * in glibc libc-lock.h?

Tags: c, gcc, glibc, typeof

Why is using three * here ? (glibc source code glibc-2.9/sysdeps/mach/bits/libc-lock.h line 81)

online view libc-lock.h code -> http://www.oschina.net/code/explore/glibc-2.9/sysdeps/mach/bits/libc-lock.h

```
/* Start a critical region with a cleanup function */
#define __libc_cleanup_region_start(DOIT, FCT, ARG)             \
{                                                               \
    typeof (***(FCT)) *__save_FCT = (DOIT) ? (FCT) : 0;         \
    typeof (ARG) __save_ARG = ARG;                              \
/* close brace is in __libc_cleanup_region_end below. */

/* End a critical region started with __libc_cleanup_region_start. */
#define __libc_cleanup_region_end(DOIT)                         \
if ((DOIT) && __save_FCT != 0)                                  \
   (*__save_FCT)(__save_ARG);                                   \
}
```

I don't know why use 3 * here, why not

```
typeof (*(FCT)) * __save_FCT = (DOIT) ? (FCT) : 0;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because it means something different, perhaps?

Comment: Does it return a pointer to a pointer to a pointer?

Comment: If i'm not wrong when given as single pointer, you may get compiler warnings when using `__save_FCT`. because when `FCT` is of type `****`, `__save_FCT` is expected to be single pointer. Otherwise when given as `(*(FCT))`, `__save_FCT` would become triple pointer.  - its my guess still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess that it's to help ensure that `FCT` is a function pointer.  When a function pointer is dereferenced, it returns a "function designator".  C99 6.5.3.2/4 "Address and indirection operators" says:

> The unary * operator denotes indirection. If the operand points to a function, the result is a function designator

And much like array names, a function designator evaluates to a function pointer except in a a couple cases. C99 6.3.2.1/4 "Lvalues, arrays, and function designators":

> A function designator is an expression that has function type. Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary & operator, a function designator with type "function returning type" is converted to an expression that has type "pointer to function returning type".

Therefore you can dereference a function pointer (or function name) an arbitrary number of times and still end up with a designator for a "function returning type".

So I think that the triple deref is there to get the compiler to complain if something other than a function pointer is used for the `FCT` macro argument.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)      If so, is it should be : typeof (***(FCT)) *__save_FCT = (DOIT) ? (**(FCT)) : 0 ; //2 deref before last FCT ??

Comment: I found the check in comments 11 years ago -> http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commitdiff;h=4ffd4002c7282cfe84f394a93fb5ad082be1820f   'syntax so both function and pointer-to-function arguments work right'

Comment: @zhao_x_g: good find (I was thinking about trying to dig through a 'blame' on that set of code, but decided I was too lazy to try). So it seems like the change takes advantage of the behavior I talk about, but has a different motivation.

Comment: @zhao_x_g: regarding the number of derefs - I think one is enough - adding more shouldn't change the behavior (each time you deref a function ptr, you get back something that's pretty much the same function ptr). I'm not sure if or why there needs to be more than two (or even one) deref in the `typeof` operand to get function names to behave the same as function pointers. But that might be because I just don't fully understand the C type system in this small area or it might be that I don't really understand the workings of `typeof` - a non-standard language feature that I never directly use.